# Input value not binding to ngmodel variable

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have an angular project I want to pass one of my input value to my typescript function but when I console.log It doesnt display updated value

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="number" [name]="'sec_chlng'" (click)="func()" 
 placeholder="Security Challenge: {{a}}+{{b}}" class="form-control form- 
 control-lg"  required></div>
```

Here`s my TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'angly-signUp',
  templateUrl: './signUp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signUp.component.scss']
})




export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
  c = this.a + this.b;
  @Input() sec_chlng :any;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  func(){
    console.log(this.sec_chlng);
  }



}
```

How to update values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `ngModel`-directive to achieve this. Whatsmore, do not react on `(click)` but on `(change)` as `(change)` gets fired after `sec_chlng` was changed whereas `(click)` is fired before. If `(change)` doesn't do the trick for you, please try `(input)`.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="sec_chlng" (change)="func()" 
placeholder="Security Challenge: {{a}}+{{b}}" class="form-control form- 
control-lg"  required>
```

And do not use `@Input`. This has another purpose.

```
sec_chlng :any;
```

This is sufficient.

EDIT:

You need to add the following Modules to your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
```

Comment: Please give a little more detail. Which component sets the value and how? Who is the parent and who is the child?

Comment: Do I get you right, that you want to enter some number into your input field and expect this value to be written into `sec_chlng`?

Comment: Referring to this assumption I updated my answer. Please, have a look.

Comment: "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'." getting this error

Comment: Please provide the entire code of your app.module or the code of the module your component is declared in.